# Campaign page related lists not deployed

Tags: deployment, page-layout, related-list, campaign

I need to add ListEmail, LandingPages, MarketingLinks, and MarketingForms as related lists to the campaign page layout. However, I don't see any changes after the Copado deployment. I committed profiles, record page, and page layout. The deployment goes without errors, but I don't see any changes in the page. Same is in classic. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that the page layout that has been deployed is assigned to the appropriate users?

Comment: @CallumMacErlich hi, yes, I have only one page layout and the assignment is correct